# FOSUserBundle redirect after authentification error

Tags: symfony

Using FSOUserBundle, and if we try to authentificate with wrong username/password we're redirect to /login route withe an error message.

I want to redifine an error route and redirect to main route with error message of corse.

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login redirection is handled by the SecurityBundle. You don't need to configured the FOSUserBundle, juste configure the `failure_path` of your firewall ([doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#redirecting-on-login-failure)) :

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                # ...
                failure_path: login_failure
```